# React Inline BackgroundImage with Media Queries

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, inline

I am working on a react app that is responsive. When the viewport shrinks or increases the 'backgroundImage' should change. I used an inline style because I was unable to use a relative path to the image which is in the public folder.

I have created a media queries within a variable in react with the widths that they should change.

I have placed the style within the .hearder-flex dive element.

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {

    const media = {
        '@media (max-width: 650px)':{
            backgroundImage: 'url("starter-code/assets/mobile/bg-pattern-header.svg")' ,
        },
        '@media (min-width: 750px)':{
            backgroundImage: 'url("starter-code/assets/tablet/bg-pattern-header.svg")' ,
        }
    }

    

    return ( 
        <div className="header-wrapper">
            <main className="header-flex" style={media}>
                    <img src="starter-code/assets/desktop/logo.svg" alt="logo" className="logo-img"/>
                    <div class="space-around">
                        <img src="starter-code/assets/desktop/icon-sun.svg" alt="icon-sun" className="sun-img"/>
                        <label className="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            <span className="slider"/>
                        </label>
                        <img src="starter-code/assets/desktop/icon-moon.svg" alt="icon-moon" className="moon-img"/>
                    </div>
            </main>
                <div className="input-search">
                    <img src="starter-code/assets/desktop/icon-search.svg" alt="icon-search" className="icon-search"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter desired job..." className="enter-job"/>
                </div>

        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, Media Queries cannot be used as the inline style.

However you can use this approach to assign the background images:

First create the css style as below and save it in a variable called css:

```
const css = `@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .backimage {
        background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
    }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .backimage {
        background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200");
    }
}`;
```

Then, use it in the component in the `style` tag above the `main` tag:

```
<style scoped>{css}</style>
<main style={{ height: 300 }} className="backimage">
```

Please also check [this sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-yalow-dqryj?file=/src/App.js:379-465)

Comment: We’re do I place this style scoped tags. I have not seen those used like that before. Do they go in the component ?

Comment: Yes yo should use it in the component. I jus updated the answer and added a sandbox link too.

Comment: Please check it and tell me if it solves your question.

Comment: This results in your styles text getting double encoded...

Comment: I've been programming React for 5 years and I never knew about this tidbit. I can't thank you enough for this information